# stopPropagation when click on a certain div

Tags: javascript

I have a div who can be displayed or not. When it's display I want to pass display to none if you click somewhere not in that div. So what I did is :

```
document.addEventListener('click',closeDiv)
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click',stopPropagation)
function closeDiv(){
    let div = document.getElementById('myDiv')
    div.style.display='none'
}
```

But with that even if I click on the div, the display goes to none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
 document.addEventListener('click',closeModal)
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click',stopPropagation)
function stopPropagation(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
function closeDiv(){
    let div = document.getElementById('myDiv')
    div.style.display='none'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you make an `window.addEventListener('click', outDiv);`

and this function :

```js
let myDiv = document.querySelector('myDiv');

function outDiv (event) {

 if (!myDiv.classList.contain(event.target)) {
  
    // Make Something
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Why would a DOM node be an element of a list of css classes? O.o